# Infering the source line number from C++ core dump

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-construction

I have a stripped down linux system for which i have to cross compile all the applications i need, on another system. These applications core often and the only information i get from it is the function which cored and the instruction offset. If i have no other option, i do an objdump on the executable, and try to guess the source code from the instruction offset and assembly snippets. This is my life.

Note: The applications are cross-compiled using g++ and are stripped down. So gdb have not helped me much

Question: 
Since the compiler/gcc has converted the source lines to assembly instructions, wouldnt there be some option which would give a correlation between the instruction offset and the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create build with `-g`, then get symbol map out of it. Save it somewhere (i would recommend saving binary with debugging symbols too - it's easier that way), then strip debugging symbols out (with `strip` program) and deploy resulting binary to target system. Here is howto: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

After it crashes, either restore dump with `-g`-compiled binary or with release binary and separate debug file. If you have crash address and binary with debugging symbols and you want to map it to source code line - you could use `addr2line -e your_binary crash_address` instead of gdb.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the source code with `-g` flag which enables the debug information, providing exactly that correlation that you are asking for.

Then, if your application crashes, you can run it in `gdb` and inspect the program state at the moment of the crash.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the line/file info if you use the non-stripped binary to debug the core file(which was generated by a stripped binary).